# Walking only specific node

Tags: python, snmp, pysnmp

I'm building a script that should get MAC/IP addresses from modem via SNMP (walk). For this purpose I'm using PySNMP and `nextCmd` (asyncore). Although I get what I want, but currently I receive more than I intended: after walking specific node it continues with all other that are left.

**Code:**

```
nextCmd(snmpEngine,
        CommunityData('private'),
        UdpTransportTarget(('IP.goes.right.here', 161)),
        ContextData(),
        ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('1.3.6.1.2.1.4.22.1.2')),
        cbFun=cbFun)

snmpEngine.transportDispatcher.runDispatcher()
```

**cbFun**

```
def cbFun(snmpEngine, sendRequestHandle, errorIndication,
      errorStatus, errorIndex, varBindTable, cbCtx):
if errorIndication:
    print(errorIndication)
    return
elif errorStatus:
    print('%s at %s' % (errorStatus.prettyPrint(),
                        errorIndex and varBindTable[-1][int(errorIndex) - 1][0] or '?'))
    return
else:
    for varBindRow in varBindTable:
        for varBind in varBindRow:
            print(' = '.join([x.prettyPrint() for x in varBind]))

return True
```

This is based purely on [documentation](http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/docs/hlapi/asyncore/manager/cmdgen/nextcmd.html) and few other examples found on the Internet.

**Sample output:**

```
1.3.6.1.2.1.4.22.1.2.536870914.some.ip.was.here = 0xMacAddress
1.3.6.1.2.1.4.22.1.3.1182728.some.ip.was.here = some.ip.was.here  # next node
1.3.6.1.2.1.4.22.1.4.1182736.some.ip.was.here = 3  # and even further
...
```

So intention for this is to be limited to walking *1.3.6.1.2.1.4.22.1.2*.

P.S. I'm just starting with PySNMP and I want something like 
`snmpwalk -v 2c -c private some.ip.was.here ipNetToPhysicalPhysAddress`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lacking any builtin methods to solve this problem I've made changes to `cbFun()`. It has now a few additional lines that contain `re.search()` and pattern is OID (so when pattern is not matched, i.e. nextCmd goes to another level (node), it just does `return`). I've made it simple and as there was already constructed string with response `print(' = '.join([x.prettyPrint() for x in varBind]))`, I've added `if` condition and assigned result of code above to a variable, so I've made it possible to implement this check.

As an another possible solution it is also possible to use approach described in [this](http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/examples/current/v3arch/oneliner/manager/cmdgen/getnext-async-multiple-transports-and-protocols.html) example - using varBindHead and comparing them.

Feel free to add your solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at adding lexicographicMode to the nextCmd attributes?

something like:

```
nextCmd(snmpEngine,
        CommunityData('private'),
        UdpTransportTarget(('IP.goes.right.here', 161)),
        ContextData(),
        ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('1.3.6.1.2.1.4.22.1.2')),lexicographicMode=False,
        cbFun=cbFun)
```

Comment: consider explaining it a little

Comment: @Pieter as I understand it's not possible in asynchronous version of nextCmd.